# Symfony2 cache is not clearing

Tags: php, symfony, caching, twig

I've been messing with the symfony twig file for two days now, trying to get my updated code to the live website.

I found a solution that i need to clear the cache.

There are some solutions that i have applied.

1. deleted `app/cache/*` folder
2. Trying to run `php app/console cache:clear`
3. `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Getting that error in case of 2-3

> // Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getClientIp() on null in /www/wwwroot/edu.gotocg.com/edu007/app/AppKernel.php on line 148
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function getClientIp() on null in /www/wwwroot/edu.gotocg.com/edu007/app/AppKernel.php on line 148
>
> cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-s|--shell] [--process-isolation] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]

4. Also tried cache warmup that is also not working.

Please help me i shall be great thankful to you.

Comment: Did you try give permission? `chmod -R 777 app/cache`

Comment: Provide the code that causes the error in `AppKernel` class. Default content of this class doesn't even have 156 lines, so I guess that your custom code causes the error.

Comment: Imanali Mamadiev, Yes I have give the permission chmod -R 777 app/cache.

Comment: There is no custom work. please see the 148 line $request variable is not initialize   
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getClientIp() on null in /www/wwwroot/edu.gotocg.com/edu007/app/AppKernel.php on line 148

Fatal error: Call to a member function getClientIp() on null in /www/wwwroot/edu.gotocg.com/edu007/app/AppKernel.php on line 148

Comment: $currentUser = new CurrentUser();
            $currentUser->fromArray(array(
                'id'        => 0,
                'nickname'  => '游客',
                'currentIp' => $this->request->getClientIp(),
                'roles'     => array()
            ));

$this->request->getClientIp() This does through the exception.

Comment: I have update the question please check the error now. by mistake placed the wrong error string.

Comment: Are you sure the code is right? I mean it is failing for a reason right? I would check where the error is coming from first and then go with the cache issue. Also please provide a full stack trace because what you've provided is not enough for us to help you

Comment: This is full stack trace which I'm getting in shell when run the cache command. Problem is that it is not make the $this->request object and return null with current request and when call its function $this->requestgetCleintIp() then through exception.

Comment: Now I have download the latest version of edusoho. 
It is open source script. 
now getting that error when run the "php app\console cache:clear --env=prod" command.
>> // Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false
>> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSchemeAndHttpHost() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\edusoho\app\AppKernel.php on line 148

Here is source file: https://github.com/edusoho/edusoho/blob/master/app/AppKernel.php